# Xml parsing by url to a listview but it displays nothing

Tags: java, android, listview, ssl-certificate

I'm reading an Xml document from url and add them to a listview. But it displaya nothing. This is my logcat.

```
 06-24 10:08:32.550: D/dalvikvm(26678): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 161K, 13% free 10115K/11568K,  paused 22ms, total 22ms

 06-24 10:08:32.550: I/dalvikvm-heap(26678): Grow heap (frag case) to 12.209MB for 1127536->byte allocation

06-24 10:08:32.570: D/dalvikvm(26678): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 12% free 11213K/12672K, >paused 17ms, total 17ms

06-24 10:08:32.590: D/AbsListView(26678): Get MotionRecognitionManager

06-24 10:08:34.790: D/AbsListView(26678): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4

06-24 10:08:34.790: D/AbsListView(26678): unregisterIRListener() is called 

06-24 10:08:34.805: D/AbsListView(26678): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0

06-24 10:08:34.805: D/AbsListView(26678): unregisterIRListener() is called 

06-24 10:08:34.825: D/libEGL(26678): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so

06-24 10:08:34.830: D/libEGL(26678): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so

06-24 10:08:34.835: D/libEGL(26678): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so

06-24 10:08:34.845: E/(26678): Device driver API match
06-24 10:08:34.845: E/(26678): Device driver API version: 23
06-24 10:08:34.845: E/(26678): User space API version: 23 
06-24 10:08:34.845: E/(26678): mali: REVISION=Linux-r3p2-01rel3 BUILD_DATE=Wed Oct 30 09:36:10 KST 2013 
06-24 10:08:34.925: D/OpenGLRenderer(26678): Enabling debug mode 0

06-24 10:08:34.925: D/AbsListView(26678): unregisterIRListener() is called 

06-24 10:08:34.945: D/AbsListView(26678): unregisterIRListener() is called 

06-24 10:08:34.960: D/AbsListView(26678): unregisterIRListener() is called
```

This is my code

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        private ListView listView;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 

              listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
              try {
                    bindDataToListing();
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }


        private void bindDataToListing()throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {

            try{
                SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance(); 
                SAXParser mSaxParser = factory.newSAXParser(); 
                XMLReader mXmlReader = mSaxParser.getXMLReader(); 
                ParsingClass pc = new ParsingClass();
                mXmlReader.setContentHandler(pc); 
               InputStream mInputStream = new URL("https://222.165.187.91/ex_rate/XML_LOLC_EXRT.xml").openStream();
               mXmlReader.parse(new InputSource(mInputStream));
               BindingData bindingData = new BindingData(this, pc.date,
                        pc.from_currency, pc.to_currency, pc.exrt_buy,
                        pc.exrt_sell);
                listView.setAdapter(bindingData);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.getMessage();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
            return true;
        }

    }
```

This is BindingData.java class

```
  public class BindingData extends BaseAdapter{

ArrayList<String> date;
ArrayList<String> from_currency;
 ArrayList<String> to_currency;
 ArrayList<String> exrt_buy;
 ArrayList<String> exrt_sell;
 LayoutInflater inflater;

 public BindingData() {

 }

 public BindingData(Activity act,ArrayList<String> date, ArrayList<String> from_currency,
   ArrayList<String> to_currency, ArrayList<String> exrt_buy,ArrayList<String> exrt_sell) {

  this.date=date;
  this.from_currency = from_currency;
  this.to_currency = to_currency;
  this.exrt_buy = exrt_buy;
  this.exrt_sell = exrt_sell;

  inflater = (LayoutInflater) act
    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
 }

 @Override
 public int getCount() {
  return date.size();
 }

 @Override
 public Object getItem(int position) {
  return null;
 }

 @Override
 public long getItemId(int position) {
  return 0;
 }

 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  Holder holder;
  if (convertView == null) {
   holder = new Holder();

   convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_row, null);
   holder.txt_date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
   holder.txt_FromCurrency = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.from_currency);
   holder. txt_toCurrency = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.to_currency);
   holder.txt_exrtBuy = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.exrt_buy);
   holder.txt_exrtSell = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.exrt_sell);
   convertView.setTag(holder);
  } else {
   holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
  }

  holder.txt_date.setText(Html.fromHtml("" + date.get(position)));
  holder.txt_FromCurrency.setText(Html.fromHtml("" + from_currency.get(position)));
  holder.txt_toCurrency.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>To Currency : </b>"+ to_currency.get(position)));
  holder.txt_exrtBuy.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>Buying : </b>" + exrt_buy.get(position)));
  holder.txt_exrtSell.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>Selling : </b>" + exrt_sell.get(position)));
  return convertView;
 }

 private class Holder {
  TextView txt_date,txt_FromCurrency, txt_toCurrency, txt_exrtBuy,txt_exrtSell;
 }
}
```

This is for trusting all certificates

```
public class MySSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

  public MySSLSocketFactory(KeyStore truststore) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
        super(truststore);

        TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager() {
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
            }

            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
            }

            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }
        };

        sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { tm }, null);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClose);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket();
    }
```

}

This is the parsing class

```
  public class ParsingClass extends DefaultHandler {

ArrayList<String> date = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> from_currency = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> to_currency = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> exrt_buy = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> exrt_sell = new ArrayList<String>();


 @Override
 public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
   Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
  super.startElement(uri, localName, qName, attributes);

  if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("Date")) {
       tempStore = "";
  }else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("From_Currency")) {
   tempStore = "";
  } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("To_Currency")) {
   tempStore = "";
  } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("exrt_buy")) {
   tempStore = "";
  } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("exrt_sell")) {
       tempStore = "";
  }else{
   tempStore = "";
  }
 }

 @Override
 public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
   throws SAXException {
  super.endElement(uri, localName, qName);

  if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("Date")) {
      date.add(tempStore);
  }
  else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("From_Currency")) {
      from_currency.add(tempStore);
  } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("To_Currency")) {
      to_currency.add(tempStore);
  } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("exrt_buy")) {
      exrt_buy.add(tempStore);
  } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("exrt_sell")) {
      exrt_sell.add(tempStore);
  }
  tempStore = "";
 }

 private String tempStore = "";

 @Override
 public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
   throws SAXException {
  super.characters(ch, start, length);
  tempStore += new String(ch, start, length);
 }
```

}

And this is the application Manifest

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.isuru.anothertry"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="11"
            android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity
                android:name="com.isuru.anothertry.MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

Comment: Do not use `StrictMode`. Use asynctask or volley for network operation

Comment: You should summarize the problem, what exactly you are facing: 1. Are you not able to read the XML, or, 2. Data is read but unable to display on ListView.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. But if I do not use Strict mode I cannot access https url due to SslError. 

My data is read. But unable to display on ListView. 
Please see my logcat.

Comment: @Isuru that is where asynctask or volley comes in for network operation.

Comment: you are returning null  in the getItem..

Comment: You posted `MySSLSocketFactory`. Can you show how you applied it to the `InputStream/Url`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
return null;
}
```

To:

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
return date.get(position);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for your support. I really appreciate it. But I found another way to do it. Strict mode did not work with it. This is my solution. Please use this method to avoid checking SSL certificate.

```
  public void trustEveryone() {
        try {
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier(){
                    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                        return true;
                    }});
            SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            context.init(null, new X509TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager(){
                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                        String authType) throws CertificateException {}
                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                        String authType) throws CertificateException {}
                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return new X509Certificate[0];
                }}}, new SecureRandom());
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(
                    context.getSocketFactory());
        } catch (Exception e) { // should never happen
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

Then call it before opening the URL.



    public void get() {
     try 
     { 
         trustEveryone();
         SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance(); 
         SAXParser mSaxParser = factory.newSAXParser(); 
         XMLReader mXmlReader = mSaxParser.getXMLReader(); 
         mXmlReader.setContentHandler(this); 
         InputStream mInputStream = new URL(URL_MAIN).openStream();

         mXmlReader.parse(new InputSource(mInputStream));
     } 
     catch(Exception e) 
     { 
         Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage()); 
     } 
 }
```

This is the only solution which worked for me. And the Sax parser example which I followed was this.

http://www.pcsalt.com/android/xml-parsing-using-saxparser-android/#sthash.Mb1Yw5uH.dpbs